# How to fix out of bounds error?

Tags: vb.net, listbox

This is the code:

```
Private Sub Video1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Video1.Tick
    ToolStripStatusLabel4.Text += 1
    currentIndex += 1
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = currentIndex
    Video1.Interval = rnd.Next(90000, 95000)
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
End Sub
```

I get an out of bouds error after the last item is selected. I want it to stop the timer when is reaches that stage. How can it be possible?

Comment: It's not very clear how currentIndex is related to the ListBox items collection when the currentIndex is updated on every tick.  The simple fix is to just check if `currentIndex < ListBox1.Items.Count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a counter to determine the total item in the listbox.

```
Dim totalItem As Integer
totalItem = ListBox1.Items.Count

'Stop the timer if the currentIndex exceeds totalItem variable.
If currentIndex = totalItem - 1 Then
     Timer1.Enabled = False
End If
```